# Case when command not working as expected in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to assign labels to my data based on certain conditions.

Following is my example code:

```
size <- 30
a <- 7:13; b <- 14:21;
L <- sapply(list(a, b), length)
EV1 <- sample(c(a, b), size = size, 
       prob = rep(c(0.42, 0.58) / L, L), replace = TRUE)

EV2 <- sample(c(4,5,6), size, replace=TRUE,
       prob = c(0.25,0.32,0.43)) %>%
       as.factor() %>%
       as.data.frame()

example_data <- as.data.frame(cbind(EV1,EV2))
colnames(example_data) <- c("EV1","EV2")

example_data <-  example_data %>% 
    mutate(
            group = case_when(
                    (EV1 >= 7 & EV1 <= 13 & EV2 == "4" | EV2 == "5") ~ 1,
                    (EV1 >= 7 & EV1 <= 13 & EV2 == "6") ~ 2,
                    (EV1 >= 14) ~ 3,
            )
    )
```

However, my output is not following the conditions.

Output

[image]

Also, my actual data contains some NAs that I want to be considered in these conditions.

Edit: I have edited to put output.

Comment: can you give an example of what does not follow the condition?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: However, I bet `case_when` evaluates in another direction than you think. Try: `case_when(     (EV1 >= 14) ~ 3,     (EV1 >= 7 & EV1 <= 13 & EV2 == "6") ~ 2,     (EV1 >= 7 & EV1 <= 13 & EV2 == "4" | EV2 == "5") ~ 1)`

Comment: Please be more specific: in the image you attach, what rows do not behave as you expect? What do you expect them to be? How do you want to "consider" `NA` values? Try using `is.na()` in your code to include them in your conditions as you want them to be handled.

Comment: (1) it is highly unlikely that we can reproduce your sample data because it is random. Please use `set.seed` before you draw from random numbers, and then rerun your code. (2) Please do not provide just a picture of data, among [many things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) it breaks screen-readers. Suggestion: please create the random data, run your code to create the wrong `group`, _manually_ add your `expected` group values, and then add the whole output from `dput(example_data)` to a code block in your question. Thanks.